# Multi-site Cache Breaking

Tags: multi-site-manager, ce-cache

I was wondering if anyone has been able to attempt Multi-site cache breaking with Ce_cache? And what did you do to achieve this?

I am trying to stay away from PHP to achieve this, and having someone to Clear the cache every time the site is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase and implement the Stash EE companion called Mustash to setup up cache clearing rules. With Mustash you'll be able to tell the Stash cach eto empty whenever an entry is modified.

http://www.devot-ee.com/add-ons/mustash